# TSAlertView not responding to delegate?

Tags: iphone, xcode, delegates

TSAlertView is TomSwift's https://github.com/TomSwift/TSAlertView/ solution to present modal views that look like UIAlertView but fully customizable. Good work!

However I fail to respond to button press in the modal dialog. I set up my viewcontroller as delegate, but there is simply no reaction.

In my own ViewController I write

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <TSAlertViewDelegate> {
```

and then I implement

```
-(void) alertView: (TSAlertView *) alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex: (NSInteger) buttonIndex {
    NSLog(@"inside");
}
```

but it never gets called. It seems like

```
[self.delegate alertView: self didDismissWithButtonIndex: buttonIndex ];
```

in TSAlertView.m has no effect.

Also there is no code about this in the Demo. Anybody ever looked at TSAlertView? Figured out how to be delegate for the buttons? Thanks!

Comment: I saw the same question at [link]http://www.techques.com/question/1-4798271/Can-I-customise-the-UIAlertView-%5BiPhone-iOs-4%5D-[/link]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TSAlertView` works pretty much the same way as a normal `UIAlertView`. Are you sure you're setting the delegate?

Here's a sample code on how I was using it, with all the delegate methods getting called as expected:

```
TSAlertView *aView = [[TSAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", @"No", nil];
    // <customize alertview>
[aView show];
[aView release];
```

You can add a breakpoint in `- (void) dismissWithClickedButtonIndex: (NSInteger)buttonIndex animated: (BOOL) animated` (in `TSAlertView.m`) and see what goes wrong and check if the delegate was set correctly.

Comment: Totally ... after some more research I realized I did not set the delegate .... aView.delegate = self ... thanks!